# Oracle Execution plan: Cost vs Actual issue: Query with higher cost runs faster

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

I know this has been asked many times before but none has a definte answer.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102477/explain-plan-cost-vs-execution-time)

[Here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:313416745628)

In my case my DBA has optimized a select query which takes around 1.05 mins to execute. I made further enhancements by making in run within 1sec. But the one which I optimized cost more in Execution plan. My DBA is suggesting since my query is costlier we should not change the query.

I know that Exection Plans for two queries are not comparable. But how should I convince my DBA to understand that Execution Plan is a "Plan" but results are "Actual"

Could anyone point me in the right direction

Comment: Your DBA should also know that comparing costs is only meaningful for different plans for the same query, not for different queries, even if they end up with the same result set. And that [cost has no unit of measurement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e16638/ex_plan.htm#i18300).

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, I guess he should know. But what are the findings, docs I can use to counter his argument

Comment: As so often, [start with Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:313416745628). But also make sure you're not just seeing the benefit of the first query having cached the data the second one then uses; run both multiple times and interleaved to check the timings are consistent.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes I did many times, and all give the same results.

Answer (score 2):

As [Tom Kyte says](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:313416745628):

> You cannot compare the cost of 2 queries with eachother.  They are simply not 
>   comparable.
>
> ...
>
> If we get another query -- another similar query -- we go through the same steps, build 
>   lots of plans, assign a cost, pick the one with the lowest cost from that set.
>
> We cannot however take those 2 queries and compare the relative cost of each to the 
>   other.  Those costs are specific to those queries.
>
> Many things influence the "cost" of a query.  The "cost" is just some artificial number 
>   we arrived at to select a query given a certain environment. ...
>
> Don't compare them, you cannot -- they might as well be random numbers.

A DBA should already know that, as should anyone trying to tune queries (and you said in the question that you do). They should also know to trust Tom's opinion.

Answer (score 1):

the calculated costs are results from statistics calculated in the past and also depend on configuration. For example if you set the optimizer_index_cost_adj , then it will effect the costs but not the actual time it takes to execute the query. And statistics that are a second old are already a second old and not 100% accurate anymore.

On the other hand, when you measure the execution time of your query, then the measured time is subject to your cache hit ratio. You can of course flush all caches before every query, but this would not resemble a live situation. So be careful when you claim that your statement takes 1.00 seconds instead of 1.05. Because you might just be doing experiments in your lab that isn't your reality.